# Negative and not significant intercept in multilevel model

Tags: interpretation, multilevel-analysis, intercept

the objective of my work is to estimate whether policies can increase men's time investment in housework. In order to estimate whether the regulation of normal weekly working hours affects men's time investment in 22 European Member States I have estimated the following model.

Here all individual level variables are coded so that 0 has a meaning (i.e. 0 hours spent in paid labor by respondent or partner, 0 contribution to household income, 0 traditional gender ideology, 0 no father, 0 no education by respondent and partner, 0 equal men of 20 years old).

Working time regulation: 35.6 to 48 max hours allowed per week in a country.

Dependent variable: min 0 and max 84 hours.

The inclusion of Working time increases the significance level of gender ideology and decreases the significance level of the intercept.

I am not positive whether I need to mention or interpret these changes. I am especially uncertain which implications this has for the intercept.

Can anyone help me with this interpretation? I am very thankful for any help.

Below, you can see the SPSS output.

Thank you, in advance!

[image]

Comment: Since age is included in your model, perhps it makes sense, since individuals who are 0 years (?) in age, and had all other variables set to zero, shouldn't be expected to contribute anything to the housework -- in fact, they'd prevent housework from occurring since they need to be cared for instead.  I can't be sure about the interpretation though since you haven't done a thorough job of explaining what all the other variables are.  For example, what on earth is "gender ideology?"  Also, are you sure this is a mixed model and not a GEE model?

Comment: Lastly, keep in mind that the intercept does not appear to be statistically significant at the 95% confidence level, so it seems it's probably no different than zero.  When you include "Working time" and it significantly changes other variables in your model this suggests you have a good deal of multicollinearity.